# эхоподавление на с++

Tags: c++, ubuntu, аудио, alsa

Реализую небольшой проект по воспроизведении аудио данных, в том числе и с микрофона. Для воспроизведения пользуюсь библиотекой soundiolib, библиотека во всем меня устраивает но наткнулся на косяк который пока что не знаю как решить. Пишу под nano pi, но так же проверяю все на своем пк на бубунте. В основном приложение готово на 90 процентов. Проблема заключается в эхоподавлении. На персональном пк за меня это делает alsa которая имеет доступ к драйверам на уровне железок в котором реализован эхо режим, в нано пи такого нет. Может кто то сталкивался с этим и готов поделится какой нибудь литературой по этому поводу? На нано пи так же стоит голая alsa